# Criando códigos únicos sequenciais para cada chave estrangeira existente

Tags: php, mysql

Considere as seguintes tabelas do MySQL:

```
Tabela 'sorteio':
sor_codigo (chave primária)
sor_nome

Tabela 'pessoas':
pes_codigo (chave primária)
pes_nome

Tabela 'numeros_da_sorte':
num_codigo (chave primária)
num_codigo_sorteio (chave estrangeira)
num_codigo_pessoa (chave estrangeira)
num_sorte (aqui é o número da sorte gerado)
```

Os números da sorte serão sempre sequenciais para cada sorteio, começando sempre do número 01.

Exemplo:

Sorteio LoteriaA - João (números da sorte = 1,2,3,4), Maria (números da sorte = 5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12), Lucas (13,14,15) e assim sucessivamente.

Sorteio LoteriaB: Marcos (números da sorte = 1,2,3), Antônio (números da sorte = 4,5,6,7), Bárbara (8,9,10) e assim sucessivamente.

Existe alguma forma de gerar no mysql algum procedimento para gerar números sequenciais únicos para cada chave estrangeira (num_codigo_sorteio)?

Conforme exemplo acima, se for necessário criar novos códigos para a LoteriaA, eles continuariam a partir do 16. Já o LoteriaB, continuaram no 11).

A quantidade de números da sorte a serem gerados para cada pessoa variam, conforme seu respectivo status registrado no sistema. Por exemplo, se a pessoa tem status 10, ele tem direito a 10 números da sorte. Se ele tem status 50, tem direito a 50 números da sorte, etc.

Utilizo PHP com Mysql.

Comment: Você quer que faça para você ou você já tentou fazer algo e está com dificuldades? Em todo caso veja se o [gerador de sequencia](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sequence-storage-engine/) do MariaDB o ajuda.

Comment: Tenho esse modelo funcionando no PHP, porém, fiz de forma que ele verifique manualmente cada novo número para garantir que o código ainda não existe. Não conheço outra forma otimizada para resolver isso.

Comment: A criação duma tabela com um único campo [auto increment](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) não seria uma solução?

Comment: Ola, Augusto. Então, se fosse apenas uma loteria, resolveria o problema. Mas considere diversas loterias (que podem acontecer de forma simultânea), cada uma com seus respectivos códigos gerados.

Comment: Uma Chave Única para garantir a integridade fora isto lock table , ler último somar um e gravar "dealocando"  a tabela, pensou em números aleatórios grandes 8, 10 dígitos testando a colisão ?